# FTC and Points of differentiability

Tags: analysis

Just having a little bit of difficulty understanding the solution to the following problem:

Let $f$ be defined as follows,

$$f(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}0, & \quad t<0, \\
t, & \quad  0\leq  t \leq 1, \\
4, & \quad t > 1. \end{array} \right.$$

(a) Determine the function $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$

(b) Sketch $F$. Where is $F$ continuous?

(c) Where is $F$ differentiable? Calculate $F$ at the points of
differentiability.

**What i've done:**

I've done part (a) and found $$F(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}0, & \quad x<0, \\
\frac{x^2}{2}, & \quad  0\leq  x \leq 1, \\
4x-\frac{7}{2}, & \quad x > 1. \end{array} \right.$$

I've also done part (b) and found that $F$ is continuous on all $\mathbb{R}$.

However, I'm having a little bit of difficulty determining where $F$ is differentiable. The solutions I have been provided simply say "$F$ is differentiable everywhere except possibly at $x=0$ and $x=1$. And then they go ahead and test the two points using the definition of differentiation.

My question is: how do they determine that $F$ is differentiable everywhere except possibly at those 2 points? I'm guessing it has something to do with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus but the definition of the FTC (that i have been given) is:

"Assume that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and define $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)~dt$$ then $F'=f$ on $(a,b)$. How do I apply this theorem to show that $F$ is differentiable everywhere except possibly at $x=0$ and $x=1$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a better theorem: If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and $F(x) = \int_a^x f,$ then $F'(x) = f(x)$ at each $x$ where $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I have not been provided that particular theorem in my course unfortunately, so I can not make use of it @zhw

Comment: I guess you don't need it. You know $F=0$ on $(-\infty,0),$ $F(x) = x^2/2$ on $(0,1),$ and $F(x) = 4x-7/2$ on $(1,\infty).$ Clearly then, $F'(x)$ exists at any $x$ in any of these intervals. That leaves only $0$ and $1$ to worry about. You just plunge in and use the definition of a derivative  at each of these two points to do this.

Comment: Yes, but that is precisely my question; is there any way to conclude from the FTC that $F'(x)$ exists at any $x$ on those intervals? Sorry for the hassle

Comment: Yes, because $f$ is actually continuous on $(-\infty, 1).$ So $F'(0) = 0.$ The FTC will be of no help in determining if $F'(1)$ exists.

Comment: Why will FTC be of no help for $F'(1)$, sorry?

Comment: Last comment: The FTC doesn't say anything about $F'(x)$ not existing.